# SQL Server stored procedure with Delete Statement gets timeout when used with powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm using PowerShell to execute a stored procedure, I will end up in a timeout.

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "Invoke-DbaQuery -Query 'EXEC [bas].[sp_xxx_Delete]' -SqlInstance xxxx\PROD\ -Database RLBCAM -verbose -QueryTimeout 1200"
```

SQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
    WHILE @FETCH_STATUS  <= @ID 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Tab = (SELET Tabelle FROM @Basis WHERE ID = @FETCH_STATUS) 
        SET @Quelle = (SELET P2 FROM @Basis WHERE ID = @FETCH_STATUS) 
        SET @Wert = (SELECT Wert FROM @Basis WHERE ID = @FETCH_STATUS) 
        SET @Zieldate = (SELET Basisdate FROM @Basis WHERE ID = @FETCH_STATUS) 

        IF @Tab <> '' 
        BEGIN
            WHILE 1 = 1 
            BEGIN 
                SET @x = CONCAT('DELETE TOP(50000) FROM ',@Tab,' WHERE ',@Quelle ,' = ', nchar(39), @Zieldate, nchar(39))           
                EXEC (@x) 
                
                IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
                    BREAK 
                WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01' 
            END                         

            SET @x = REPLACE(@x, 'TOP(50000)', '*') 
            EXECUTE bas.proc_WriteLog 'bas.SP.xxxxx_Delete', 0, 'I', @x, 0, '', @Date1, @VDate, 'Delete ...' 
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT CONCAT('Dead ID:', @FETCH_STATUS) 
        END

        SET @FETCH_STATUS = @FETCH_STATUS + 1 
    END
END TRY
```

It finally fails with a timeout

> VERBOSE: delete Top(50000) from bas.tbl_xxxx where source = '2020-08-11'
> VERBOSE: delete Top(50000) from bas.tbl_xxxx where source = '2020-08-11'
> WARNING: [11:38:03][Invoke-DbaQuery] [] Failed during execution | The wait operation timed out

The stored procedure **doesn't fail** with a timeout when started in SQL Server Management Studio.

No other job is running while executing this stored procedure. It always fails after about 5 min when shell is used.

The DELETE statements delete around 2 mio records in 50000 packages per data day. The full job will delete about 50 mio records from several tables, no joins, always the same statement, other date and tablename. Packagesize of 50000 is valid for all statements.

No difference when using a smaller size, e.g. 10000 or a longer timeout period. Max timeout was 20 hours, same effect.

Memory peak was 350 MB. System offers 128 GB Memory. Space on disk storage > 1 TB.

SQL Server 2019

MMC 2018, valid for server version

Comment: There are typos in your SQL eg: `(SELET Tabelle FROM @Basis WHERE ID = @FETCH_STATUS)`. I doubt it can run without error.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand very well your ultimate purpose. You say "The stored procedure doesn't fail with a timeout when started in SQL Server Management Studio." but how long does it take on average ? It could still take a long time, simply your query run in SQL Studio is not subject to the preset timeout. I have the impression that you are reading from a cursor and the code is not complete. You might want to put some prints inside your loop and spit out the current date/time, at least see if the loop is being run albeit slowly.

Comment: And you have a `WAITFOR` inside the loop, it's not clear why, but the more iterations in your loop, the longer it will take since you are adding an arbitrary delay. You have at least two options: 1) add a print statement after each operation,show the date/time and try to identify the bottlenecks in your code and 2) run an execution plan against your stored procedure - it should tell you quite a lot.

Comment: what does the 'max server memory' say in Server properties in SSMS?

Comment: My hunch is its more like a memory problem than a standard SQL timeout. You're not getting 'timeout expired', you're getting 'the wait operation timed out' which can be an internal SQL resource juggling message - see this https://serverfault.com/questions/419997/the-wait-operation-timed-out-when-running-sql-server-in-hyper-v

Comment: the job normally runs about 60 minutes. Ignore the typos, copy issue. The Waitfor is just a try, based of a hint, doesnt matter. Max server memory 128 GB.